# EF Core - What is the correct configuration?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I have the following model:

```
public class Book 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<IndexPage> IndexPages { get; set; }
}

public class IndexPage 
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<IndexWord> Words { get; set; }

    public int IndexType { get; set; }
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
}

public class IndexWord {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public IndexPageId { get; set; }
}
```

It is configured with the following configuration:

```
public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
    {
         builder.ToTable("Books");
         builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

         builder.HasMany(b => b.IndexPages)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.BookId);
    }
}

public class IndexPageConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IndexPage>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IndexPage> builder)
    {
         builder.ToTable("IndexPages");
         builder.HasKey(ip => new { ip.BookId, ip.IndexType });

         builder.HasMany(ip => ip.IndexWords)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(iw => iw.IndexPageId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(ip => ip.Id);

        builder.HasIndex(ip => ip.Id).IsUnique();
    }
}

public class IndexWordConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IndexWord>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IndexWord> builder)
    {
         builder.ToTable("IndexWords");
         builder.HasKey(iw => iw.Id);

         builder.Property(iw => iw.Value).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

---

Some context; The queries are performed with `AsNoTracking()` and the update is called as following:

```
DbContext.Set<Book>.Update(book);
```

If the book is updated, the indexpages are in total replaced with a new set of indexpages.
If calling update the first time it all **seems** to work correctly and inserts the rows. However when called the second time it raises an Primary Key constraint exception; Which makes sense, however I expected the old indexpages to be removed and the new indexpages to be inserted. Due to the fact that the primary key exists and update is called, **not Add**.

The reason behind the composite key is that a book can only have a fixed subset of indexpages. this is also the reason why the `HasPrincipalKey` has been used.

When only using the IndexPage Id as a key in the configuration. The relation between the book exists, but it just keeps inserting new indexpages on top of the old indexpages (I guess due to the AsNoTracking?). 
Furthermore, in the code behind I add the indexpages on the book, but these initially have empty id's.

Comment: Are the old IndexPages simply just not being deleted in the database, or are the old IndexPages also staying attached to the Book along with the new ones ?

Comment: Sorry, with the composite key it raises an pk constraint. With the single Id as key it inserts it next to the existing rows, so they stay attached.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use no tracking ? If EF Core doesn't track the original entity returned from the query, it can't tell that you've modified it by updating it with new IndexPages.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-2.2) `Update` begins tracking the entity. Which means that if you modify it, it's enough to call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` for it to be saved. If you call `Update` on a tracked entity it tries to insert it.

Comment: I understand it inserts it after an update, but my question here is; I want only the new indexpages to exist after the update and the old rows to be deleted. Shouldn't the old rows be deleted since the object that has been updated does not have those rows anymore?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the old `IndexPage` entities are not being replaced by the new ones when you attempt to Update ?

You mentioned that you're using No Tracking for your queries. Without tracking the original entity, returned from your query, EF Core has no way to tell that the entity has been modified. If you want the new `IndexPage` objects to replace the old ones, then you need to track the queries and configure the delete behavior for your relationships.

You can look at the EF Core docs for a reference regarding required relationships and delete behaviors. Be careful to configure these things on the proper entities, so you don't end up deleting everything by removing an `IndexPage`.

Allow for change tracking and configure if the relationships are required and their delete behavior. That should accomplish what you're seeking to achieve.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration